# Why is cookie hashcode changing, when now new cookie is added in subsequent responses?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, servlets, cookies

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("text/html");

Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(null != cookies) {
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        out.println(cookie);
        out.println("<br>");
    }
} else {
//Set the Cookie in response, so that you can retrieve this in subsequent requests
    Cookie PegaRULES = new Cookie("PegaRULES", "This is PegaRULES Cookie");
    response.addCookie(PegaRULES);
}
```

}

Hello everyone,

I've above code, Ideally it is supposed to do following

for 1st request, as there would be no PegaRULES cookie, it should add one in the response

from second request on wards, same cookie should be printed on browser (i mean the ClassName@hashcode of cookie like Cookie@Ac35c)

My observations

For first request, blank page (as expected) and in the response the cookie is present

for second request, Cookie@af33d (say)

for all subsequent requests, it should not change (i.e. same Cookie@af33d should be printed on browser)
But, I see the value changed on each subsequent request (i do refresh the browser each time, to fire subsequent requests)

FYI, I'm using Fiddler to trace the requests and responses

and I don't see any cookie in subsequent responses from 2nd request on wards (and this is as expected).. I'm more concerned about the value printed on browser, which is changed each time i refresh the browser (i.e. fire a new request)

PS : same is the behavior with both IE and Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html), The `javax.servlet.http.Cookie`class does not override `Object#hashCode`, therefore the hash code of its instance is not based on the values set on it, but is more or less randomly assigned to each individual instance.

Since each request gets a fresh instance of `Cookie`, the result is a different hash code each time.

Comment: why should each request get a fresh instance of cookie?  
If you look at the logic present there, it is supposed to send cookie only once and its working that way.  
I see only one cookie send as part of first response, and subsequent responses don't contain any..  
I was talking about this specific case, there should be no new instance right?